# Unable to find DLL when website runs in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, c++, iis

When I run the website locally using my VS, everything works.

I am calling a function inside a dll using P/Invoke. DLL is in C++ and it works.

When I deploy the website on IIS, I get the error message

```
Unable to load DLL 'SolvingProbelm.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

The dll resides inside the bin folder.  App pool is Classic and .net 2.0

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Just a guess, does your assembly have to be in a folder listed in the `Path` environment variable?

Comment: Check out the DLL's dependencies using http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Is the spelling error in the DLL name intentional? To gather some more detail on the problem, use dependencywalker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check if the dll has unresolved dependencies.

Comment: It works on locally on VS but when deployed to local IIS, it doesn't work and shows this error message.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996263/how-do-i-get-iis-to-load-a-native-dll-referenced-by-my-wcf-service to get more information.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996263/how-do-i-get-iis-to-load-a-native-dll-referenced-by-my-wcf-service for more information.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996263/how-do-i-get-iis-to-load-a-native-dll-referenced-by-my-wcf-service for more information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get IIS to load a native DLL referenced by my WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996263/how-do-i-get-iis-to-load-a-native-dll-referenced-by-my-wcf-service)

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the similar problem once. Just copy `SolvingProbelm.dll` to `C:\WINDOWS\System32`. Hopefully, it will work! It had worked in my situation. Actually native DLLs and .Net DLLs are searched differently. IIS searches native DLLs in `C:\Windows\System32` folder also. So copying your DLLs there solves problems!

Comment: I've added in system32 folder but no success.

Answer (score 1):

Today I faced this same problem with a software a little bit old (ASP.NET). As you can see here:

[image: ImageError]

Finally I found the explanation to my problem here [How do I get IIS to load a native DLL referenced by my WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996263/how-do-i-get-iis-to-load-a-native-dll-referenced-by-my-wcf-service) Please, take a look it solved all my doubts.

Comment: If you think this is the same problem, consider flagging as a duplicate instead of providing an answer

Comment: Hi Alex, yeah sure! How can I do it? (I think I'm not able to do this because I've not enough reputation)

Comment: Ok, I proposed a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 10 years. But if someone should encounter the problem again, just make sure that **Platform** and **Configuration** have not changed in **Project Properties** under **Build**. In my case, Visual Studio had simply changed the Platform to **All Platforms** even though I had built all dlls before using **Any CPU**.