# How do I get IIS to load a native DLL referenced by my WCF service?

Tags: c++, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service that contains some C# code, which references a C++/CLI dll, which references some native DLLs.  I include all of the necessary DLLs in the bin folder for my IIS application, but when IIS loads the managed DLLs, it seems to be copying them to a deep directory like:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\testwcf\73473be6\e625098c\assembly\dl3\aada7c33\85a7332b_2f9acc01
```

It copies each managed DLL to its own directory and loads it.  When it gets to my C++/CLI DLL, it copies it to a directory like above, and then it is unable to load the dependencies.  If I manually copy all of the native DLLs into this folder, it will run, but that's not a great solution.

My web.config is the stock one created by VS, with an endpoint defined based on an MSDN article.

```
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService.Service1">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="WcfService.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

How can I get these DLLs to be picked up automatically?

Comment: contents of your web.config will help to understand it better

Comment: yep cant see any thing wrong, how about your AppPool is it 32 bit enabled ? you can find your app pool under IIS\Application Pools and then select one under which you are running your web application

Comment: All DLLs are compiled to x64, and the problem isn't related to that.  They load fine when I put them next to the managed DLL in the place that ASP.NET creates.  I just need ASP.NET to pick them up from the bin directory that all of the managed DLLs are being loaded from.

Comment: @Surjit Samra The final missing piece after accidentally wiping out my Temporary ASP.NET Files directories was setting Enable 32-bit Applications advanced to True on the app pool. My projects were compiled for the AnyCPU platform and did not have adequate permissions to create the temporary directories. After recreating the directory and adding Modify and Write permissions (shortcut: enable Full Control, then disable it) to my IIS_IUSRS group, my application pool was able to work again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jorman/loading-c-assemblies-in-asp-net), it seems that the native DLLs need to be available in certain directories or on the path:

> The core cause to this problem is in the way the operating system
> loads native DLL's at runtime. Native DLL's are loaded using the
> following logic which does not include the Temporary ASP.net Files nor
> the applications /bin folder. This problem will also occur in any .Net
> application if the Native DLL is not included in the /bin folder with
> the .EXE file or if the DLL is not in the Path Environment Variable.
>
> 1. The directory from which the application loaded.  In the case of
>    ASP.Net, this will resolve to %windir%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v###
>    or %windir%\system32\inetsrv for IIS 6.
> 2. The current directory.  In the case of ASP.Net, this will resolve to %windir%\System32\inetsrv
>    for IIS 6.  If using the built-in web server, this resolves to a path
>    under C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8.
> 3. The Windows system
>    directory.  Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of
>    this directory.
> 4. The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory
>    function to get the path of this directory.
> 5. The directories that are
>    listed in the PATH environment variable.

The solutions offered are as follows:

> 1. Use DLLImport to load the dll using a relative or absolute path at
>    runtime.
> 2. Set the PATH Environment Variable so the ASP.Net process can
>    locate the C++ DLL.  You can set this property at runtime so that it
>    only affects the process running your code.  You can also set this
>    globally in the System Properties (Environment Variables | PATH
>    property). Setting this programmatically does not require a reboot and
>    you can point the PATH to the /bin folder of the web app if you want
>    to be able to do XCopy deployments of your ASP.Net application.  Here
>    are the steps to set the Path programmatically from ASP.Net.

There are also some more complex solutions related to #2 which involve programmatically updating the PATH.