# ASP.NET could not load type 'WebApplication1.Global'

Tags: asp.net

I created a project (ASP.NET empty web application) `WebApplication1`.
I also have Default.aspx/login.aspx/GoogleCallBack.aspx

when I run the application, the error shows

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WebApplication1.Global'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Global" Language="C#" %>

Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1
```

Does anyone know how to fix it ?  thank you

Comment: Recompile your project and check for errors.

Comment: Hi Slaks, i did, the errors showed up the same as posted

Comment: No; look for compiler errors in the error list.

Comment: the name "OpenAuth" does not exist in the current conext

Comment: You need to fix your compiler errors.

Comment: do you know what's the openAuth?

Comment: http://dotnetopenauth.net/ You may be missing a NuGet package.

Comment: I already tried these commends in Package Manager Console  Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth 
  and 
Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet

Comment: but error still shows up

Answer (score 2):

Just Check Project **->** Properties **->** Web

Project Url --- Click on (Create Virtual Directory)link **=>** This will ask you to map to correct folder location say ok.

This problem Occured when we move our project to different directory and IIS still refers to old directory.

Answer (score 0):

Does your project have a "Global.asax.cs"?  If so, does it compile?

F5 is for "Debug."  This is about building the solution.  Ctrl+Shift+B would be the hot-key combination to build and look for compiler errors.

Comment: yes, I have Global.asax.cs    could you tell me how to compile this file?  press F5?

Comment: Right-click the file and choose "Properties" make sure Build Action is set to "Compile". Also check that your global class is inside the WebApplication1 namespace and that the class is called "Global".

Answer (score 0):

This topic is a duplicate of ["Parser Error Message: Could not load type" in Global.asax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682216/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-in-global-asax).

The most voted answer is provided by Facio Ratio: Your local web server is running different code than what you're actually working on. Ensure you have stopped debugging, stop your local web server, clean and rebuild as Peter suggested, double-check your global.asax and global.asax.cs, and try again. If this doesn't work and you are using local IIS, try removing the site in IIS Manager and recreating it manually.

Comment: Not a duplicate. This topic has answers that are not included in the linked question. With 20+ causes of the vague load error, many answers are needed.