# Error in Global.asax when I try to run project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Hello I have problem with ASP MVC application when I try to run it I have error like in image:
[image]

But when other guys try to run project in their laptops all works correctly.

Comment: Looks to me like it hasn't been built

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this issue by Check  the project output path (project properties / Build) is set to bin and not bin\Release or bin\Debug
or try to clean solution and rebuild again

Comment: there is bin\, and tryed to clean and rebuild

Comment: @Abbath [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682216/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-in-global-asax)

Answer (score 1):

Clean your solution and rebuild - that should take care of it.