# Cannot fix Global.asax error: "Could not load type 'ApplicationName.Global"

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, compiler-errors, runtime-error, global-asax

When rebuilding my application I've encountered the following error:

[image]

I've tried deleting the global.asax file and re-adding one with the same content of a code commit I did when it worked.

I dont think its IIS either, when I run other projects they still work.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682216/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-in-global-asax

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Parser Error Message: Could not load type" in Global.asax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682216/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-in-global-asax)