# Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'PresentationLogic.Global'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing issue while running my web application and getting this error message.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error    Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'PresentationLogic.Global'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs"
>   Inherits="PresentationLogic.Global" Language="C#" %> Line 2:  <%@
>   Import Namespace="System.Diagnostics" %> Line 3:
>
> Source File:  /global.asax    Line:  1

Comment: Is there any assembly in your bin folder which contains a type named PresentationLogic.Global?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Parser Error Message: Could not load type" in Global.asax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682216/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-in-global-asax)