# How to use native DLL in a deployed website (IIS 7)

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, dll

I'm consuming a 32-bit native DLL from a c# web service. Everything works fine locally in VS with IIS express. However when I deployed the site to an IIS hosting provider (IIS 7) the calls to the DLL (using platform invoke) did not work (no error, it doesn't even return from the call and the web service is terminated abruptly). However, the client side is notified via PageMethod error function: "Unable to load DLL access is denied (exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

Since the provider IIS is running 64-bit mode, I asked them to change my process to 32-bit, however that didn't make any difference.
Do I need to do anything special to use native DLLs on IIS 7? Do I have to register native modules with the server before they can be used? Any explanation for the weird behavior when the DLL is called?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may have already searched, but it appears that this question has already been asked:  See [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996263/how-do-i-get-iis-to-load-a-native-dll-referenced-by-my-wcf-service) here, but what it boils down to having the dll in the right place and setting PATH variables.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My native DLL is in the /bin folder. I did try to load the DLL by specifying full path and that didn't help. The weird thing is that I don't get any error even if I delete the DLL. I placed debug logs immediately before and after calling the imported DLL function, the log indicates it reached the point before the call but never the point after the call and the web service is terminated at this point, however, the client side is notified via PageMethod error function: "Unable to load DLL access is denied (exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"